# (De)activate multiple NSLayoutConstraints?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm having an `UIView` with two subviews:

- `UIActivityIndicatorView`
- `UIlabel`

The `UIView` size is based on the `UIActivityIndicatorView` and `UIlabel` with `NSLayoutConstraints`.

At first the top of the `UIView` is linked to the top of the `UIActivityIndicatorView`, when I want to de-activate that constraint and activate the one with the top of the `UIView` linked to the top of the `UIlabel` I'm doing this:

```
_labelLayoutConstraintTopToSuperViewTop.active = YES;
_labelLayoutConstraintTopToActivityIndicatorViewBottom.active = NO;
```

This will result in an warning, but when I'm switching this to this:

```
_labelLayoutConstraintTopToActivityIndicatorViewBottom.active = NO;
_labelLayoutConstraintTopToSuperViewTop.active = YES;
```

I'm no longer getting the warning, until I link the top of the view to the `UIActivityIndicatorView` again.

Is there any way to put these changes in a batch or something? Am I misunderstanding something? I tried to use `setNeedsUpdateConstraints`, `updateConstraintsIfNeeded`, `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded` as well, all without success.

I hope I'm clear enough, thnx.

Answer (score 1):

F this, I can't figure it out.

As soon as I activate a constraint I get a warning about a constraint that I probably don't want, and that's correct, because I'm de-activating that constraint on the next line!

My fix for now is to just attach the top of the label to the top of the activity indicator and increase/decrease the constant as needed.

Comment: I'm running into something similar. I'd like a batch NSLayoutConstraint method that enables you to simultaneously apply a series of activates/deactivates, but can't appear find that.

Comment: @ChrisPrince you can do that, but just with activate or deactivate, see this for example: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1526955-activate

edit: I think you already knew that, but just in case :)

Comment: Nodding. Right. I was looking for something of the form `NSLayoutConstraint.change({constraint1.isActive = false, constraint2.isActive = false...})`